# getting bad exception while linking with twitter

Tags: iphone, twitter

i am following link (http://aralbalkan.com/3133) for integrating my app with twitter. I followed each and every stepp provided in this link, but i am getting the error in gdb :

```
 2011-08-04 17:33:32.037 XAuthTwitterEngineDemo[5533:1f0b] access token did fail ***************
```

and give bad exception at this method although i am providing my correct username and password. here is my code

```
- (void) twitterXAuthConnectionDidFailWithError: (NSError *)error;
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    UIAlertViewQuick(@"Authentication error", @"Please check your username and password and try again.", @"OK");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your provided token or secret key is invalid. Verify it again and also check the type of access your application is having.

**Modified:**

[From here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/oauth/xauth), you will able to follow the steps to have authentication.

Comment: thanks for showing interest toward my problem, but i copied the consumer key and secret key from my account on twitter that was generated after submission. my access type is read and write

Comment: in aral balkan blog there is also written "ask for xAuth to be activated on your account by opening a support ticket. Make sure that you include the App ID of your app in your support ticket. The App ID is the number at the end of the URL on your app's Twitter page (e.g., http://twitter.com/oauth_clients/details/your_app_id)."

Comment: Yeah..I have modified the answer. Just go through the link and you shall have idea about it.

Comment: thanks for giving me idea... can u tell me what will be my Oauth_nonce, timestamp, xAuth_mode, password, username?